# Is this convergent or divergent: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is this convergent or divergent? if convergent, find the sum. If divergent explain why.

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1}$$

I want to use the divergent test which is $\mathrm{If\:}\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n\ne 0\mathrm{\:then\:}\sum a_n\mathrm{\:diverges}$

$\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1}$  I would assume to take out the largest $n$ in both the top and bottom

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2}\cdot \frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)\:$

having the $n^2$ cancel

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}$ after taking the limit

$\frac{2}{5+0+0}$

so $\frac{2}{5}$$\ne $ $\:0\:$ so it's divergent?

Comment: You've got it right on the money! You could always try the other tests if you ever doubt yourself. That way when you get the same answer you'll know you're 100% right.

Comment: Intuitively, this is what the test measures $$\sum _{n=1}^{\text{a very large number}}\:\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1} + \sum _{n=\text{a very large number}}^{\infty }\:\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1}\approx k+\sum _{n=\text{a very large number}}^{\infty }\:\frac{2}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly right.  Well done.

Comment: Also, in similar problems you will generally evaluate the limit by factoring out the largest power in the denominator, so 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {2n^3 \over 5n^2 + 2n + 1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {2n \over 5 + 2/n + 1/n^2}  = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {2n\over 5} = \infty$$

and

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {2n \over 5n^2 + 2n + 1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {2/n \over 5 + 2/n + 1/n^2}  = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {2/n \over 5} = 0$$